# Using shell script code passed as an argument to a function

Tags: bash

having issue getting command to execute threw a function in a BASH script.

The command: `[named -V|grep BIND|awk '{printf ($2);}']` works in a shell but will not set the output to a varable.

Desired output for `$VER` should be: `9.8.1-P1`

I believe the issue is the |

However, I am receiving:

```
BIND 9.8.1-P1 built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
```

if you have any info please let me know

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
function version {
  if [ `builtin type -p $3` ]; then
    VER=`$2`
    if [[ -n $VER ]]; then
#     echo "$VER" > $DIR/ver/$1
      echo "VER=$VER"
      PID=$(pidof $3)
      if [[ -n "$PID" ]]; then
#       echo "$PID" > $DIR/pid/$1
       echo "PID=$PID"
      fi
    fi
  else
    echo "$1 not installed"
  fi
}
version "bind" "named -V|grep BIND|awk '{printf ($2);}'" "named"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want: `VER=$(eval "$2")`  -- The quotes are very important to contain the eval'ed script as a single word.

You will also need to alter the 2nd argument:

```
"named -V|awk '/BIND/ {print \$2}'"
#                            ^^^
```

Without the backslash, the shell would see `$2` inside double quotes and substitute it.

The grep is removed simply because it's not necessary: awk can search for patterns.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. i have been banging my head on the desk for 4 hours now

Comment: what is the deal with '/BIND'/ ? i understand the escaped chars
NeverMind i see you combined AWK and GREP

Comment: Why are we encouraging the OP to use `eval` at all? It's certainly not in line with best practices.

Answer (score 1):

See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a detailed discussion of why commands should not be stored in strings (and how and why this fails in practice), and [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) describing why `eval` in particular is error-prone.

A far safer approach is to store code in functions, and pass those functions by name:

```
get_named_version() { named -V | awk '/BIND/ {print $2}'; }
version bind get_named_version named
```

...will work correctly with your original function.